# How to timeout ibase_connect?

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to implement a timeout while connecting to a firebird 2.5 db.

This is for a script that connects to 150+ servers. My goal is too fail that server and move to the next one, in order to maintain script executing time.

Normal script execution time is 30seconds, but if one server fails it raises up to 300seconds.
I'm using ibase extension on PHP 7.

Any advices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a property `isc_dpb_connect_timeout`, but 1) I'm not sure how you can configure it with `ibase_connect`, and 2) IIRC it only comes into effect after connecting to the server but before attaching to the database (which kind of defeats the purpose IMHO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection timeout option exists on server side for sure, on client you can try set it in firebird.conf 
How about test if port is opened before do connect ?

```
<?php

function con_test($i, $p) {
    $f = @fsockopen($i, $p, $errno, $errstr, 0.1);
        if (!$f) {
            return false;
        } 
        else {
            fclose($f);
            return true;
        }
}   


$host[] = ['ip'=>'192.168.52.97','port' => '3050', 'alias' => 'test'];
$host[] = ['ip'=>'192.168.52.96','port' => '3050', 'alias' => 'test'];

$username='sysdba';
$password = 'masterkey';

foreach ($host as $k=>$v)
 {
 if (con_test($v['ip'],$v['port'])) { 

    $host = $v['ip'].'/'.$v['port'].':'.$v['alias'];
    $dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $stmt = 'SELECT \'test\' as test FROM rdb$database';
    $sth = ibase_query($dbh, $stmt);

    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($sth)) {
    echo $row->TEST, PHP_EOL;
    }
    ibase_free_result($sth);
    ibase_close($dbh);
} 
else  {
    echo 'Cannot connect to '.$v['ip'].':'.$v['port'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

}